# why <div> tag have spaces in both left and right sides whose width is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, expand

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main_div{
width:100%;
height:200px;
background-color:#111111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_div"></div>       
</body>
</html>
```

why  tag have spaces in both left and right sides whose width is set to 100%? i want to fill all the spaces with div like so many web sites including the header bar in this site also. how can  i do that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMpWD.jpg "image"

Comment: every web browser has a built in "user agent" style. you need to override it by setting margins/paddings/sizes to 0 for all elements at the beginning of your style sheet.

Comment: Some browsers automatically style some elements, like 'lists' for example. To get around this, you need to reset the css on all elements, try this reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: use body{
margin:0px;
padding0px;
}

Comment: thank you all of you. now i got it. and "body{ margin:0px; padding0px; } " worked. thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default CSS Styles
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

By default `body` takes `margin: 8px`. add `body { margin: 0 }` to your css.
See the following snippet for ref.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#main_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
body{
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```